# add input fields if user is logged in

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-fields

I want to add two custom fields inside comments on a CPT after the user is logged in on.

This is the code for creating the custom fields:

```
function debate_comment_fields( $fields ) {
    if(is_singular('debate') && is_user_logged_in()) {
        $fields['first'] = '<p class="comment-form-first"><label for="first">' . 
            __( 'HTML5' ) . 
            '</label>' . 
            '<input id="first" name="category" type="radio" value="'.get_post_meta($post->ID, 'agree', true).'" /></p>';
        $fields['second'] = '<p class="comment-form-second"><label for="second">' . 
            __( 'FLASH' ) . 
            '</label>' .
            '<input id="second" name="category" type="radio" value="'.get_post_meta($post->ID, 'disagree', true).'" /></p>';
        return $fields;
    } else {
        return $fields;
    }
} 
add_filter('comment_form_default_fields','debate_comment_fields');
```

After I'm logged in I can not see the new fields, If I remove the `&& is_user_logged_in()` and check without being logged in is working.

So, I assume that something is wrong with the `&& is_user_logged_in()` or maybe I should use another function.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: It is strange as is_user_logged_in() is the Wordpress function to check that.
What version of WP are you using ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange, that should work.

Maybe try this??

```
if ( 'debate' == get_post_type() && is_user_logged_in() ) {

//do stuff

}
```